# urxvt screen flashing when redrawing

Tags: windows, console, rxvt

I have a simple test script that runs fine with xterm but I cannot see the output when using urxvt because the screen flashes and I only see the cursor on the top left corner. Here is the script:

```
i=0

while [ 1 ] ; do
    echo "test$i"
    ((++i));
    echo -e "\033c"
done
```

I tried using `urxvt*buffered: true` in `.Xresources` but it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want any flickering, don't reset (`ESC c`) the terminal at every loop:

```
i=0
echo -e '\033c'
while : ; do
    echo -e '\033[H'"test$i"
    ((++i))
done
```

Comment: On some terminal emulators that simply results in a different kind of flicker, with the cursor appearing at different points on the first line.

Comment: By adding `\033[2K` to the homing of the cursor you can probably remove the flickering. My mistake was resetting the terminal every "frame".

Comment: No, EL causes yet another flicker pattern on those terminal emulators.  Your mistake is in thinking that this sort of thing is inherently free from screen erase and cursor motion being out of phase with window rendering.  It isn't.  Across a range of terminal emulators you will get a range of effects, with RIS, ED, EL, or simply only CUP 1,1.  Try it.  (-:

Answer (score 3):

It’s not clear what you expect from a script that
continually writes text to the screen and then immediately erases it. 
It looks like you are observing that urxvt runs faster than xterm. 
If you want to see the output from your script, add a sleep.

Comment: I was not sure if urxvt was just faster than xterm or if there was some kind of double buffer problem with urxvt.

Comment: The script is issuing RIS.  Change that to ED and xterm runs a whole lot faster.

Comment: @JdeBP: I’m not sure what you’re saying, and I’m especially puzzled why you’re saying it as a comment on my answer rather than a comment on the question (or maybe even as a separate answer).

Comment: Because it _is_ a comment on your answer, which is talking about urxvt running "faster than xterm".  As I said, xterm handles ED a lot faster than it does RIS, and the speed difference between it and urxvt is no longer orders of magnitude.

Comment: (1) Well, I still don’t know what “RIS” and “ED” are. (OK, I’m guessing that ED is “erase display”, but I still don’t know what RIS is, and it’s not worth the bother to Google it and go into TLA hell.) (2) Your comment seems to be beside the point, as my point is that urxvt runs *too* fast for the OP’s liking, and getting xterm to run faster isn't in anybody’s interest.